# Creating a POST request with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, request

I want to create an ajax call with the following data in the body

```
{
   locations:[
      {latLng:{lat:51.524410144966154,lng:-0.12989273652335526}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.54495915136182,lng:-0.16518885449221493}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.52061842826141,lng:-0.1495479641837033}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.52850609658769,lng:-0.20170525707760403}}
   ]
}
```

Composing the POST with fiddler worked perfectly and resulted in following POST request:

```
POST http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=MYKEY HTTP/2.0
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: www.mapquestapi.com
Content-Length: 289

{
   locations:[
      {latLng:{lat:51.524410144966154,lng:-0.12989273652335526}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.54495915136182,lng:-0.16518885449221493}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.52061842826141,lng:-0.1495479641837033}},
      {latLng:{lat:51.52850609658769,lng:-0.20170525707760403}}
   ]
}
```

I tried to make the same request with an ajax call in JS:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=MYKEY',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({locations:
        [
        {latLng:{lat:51.524410144966154,lng:-0.12989273652335526}},
        {latLng:{lat:51.54495915136182,lng:-0.16518885449221493}},
        {latLng:{lat:51.52061842826141,lng:-0.1495479641837033}},
        {latLng:{lat:51.52850609658769,lng:-0.20170525707760403}}
        ]})
    }).done(function(data){
         console.log(data);
     });
```

This resulted into following POST request and an error.

```
POST http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=MYKEY HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mapquestapi.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 459
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

locations%5B0%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blat%5D=51.524410144966154&locations%5B0%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blng%5D=-0.12989273652335526&locations%5B1%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blat%5D=51.54495915136182&locations%5B1%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blng%5D=-0.16518885449221493&locations%5B2%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blat%5D=51.52061842826141&locations%5B2%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blng%5D=-0.1495479641837033&locations%5B3%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blat%5D=51.52850609658769&locations%5B3%5D%5BlatLng%5D%5Blng%5D=-0.20170525707760403
```

Error

```
"Error parsing JSON from Request: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of ,  Please see the documentation for the Directions Service at http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/ for details on correctly formatting requests."
```

I did try it in several different ways but nothing seems to help.
What is wrong with the ajax call?

Comment: Try without `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Hi Nora, I did try that but the result is the same.

Comment: Try add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Default `contentType` is form encoding...use `application/json` as metntioned